# Following instructions to build LLVM to the letter, but executables aren't produced

Tags: linux, gcc, llvm, compilation, clang

I am running 64-bit Linux and I am attempting to build the LLVM trunk. I follow the [instructions to the letter](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#config), and invoke configure with the arguments I want, followed by make. Running make install leaves each directory with no action, and running locate on a name of an llvm executable (such as clang) comes up with no results.

I do not understand what could be wrong here, but I am quite sure that no executables are produced. This exact process works for software in general. Is there some absurdly obvious thing that I am missing?

I'm using gcc 4.5 and 3.81.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you asked for debug or release build, you can check the stuff inside bin subdir of Debug or Release (alternatively, Debug+Assert, Release+Assert) directory in your build directory for the binaries.

If there is still nothing, then you can go to tools/ and invoke make directly to check what's going there. Doing "make VERBOSE=1" might provide some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to say what's happening and maybe take a look at what's going on and how exactly you invoked configure and make.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what has been working for me on the last 4 or so Ubuntu 64 bit distros.

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd llvm
cd tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd ..
./configure --enable-optimized --disable-doxygen --prefix=/llvm
make
make install
```